# Using flow inside jest test file results in undefined test, expect etc

Tags: reactjs, testing, flowtype, jestjs

I have a simple test.js file

```
// @flow
import React from "react";
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";
import RatioImage from "./";

test("<RatioImage /> base case should render correctly", () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<RatioImage width={100} ratio={1} source={{ uri: "" }} />);
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Adding flow inside there works within `renderer` which is nice, however `test` and `expect` cause flow errors as they are not defined. Is there any way to set them as globals of some sort so flow doesn't error them?

Comment: Have you tried to use the [flow-typed](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed) definitions from https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/tree/master/definitions/npm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand a little bit on what Andreas said in a comment, Flow lets you create library definitions for external libraries. (As I'm assuming you're using Jest here). (These are sometimes called `libdefs`)

When someone creates a global library, they can declare a function (or class!) to be global with the `declare function` or `declare class` syntax, documented on the [Flow libdef documentation](https://flow.org/en/docs/libdefs/creation/) page.

For the most part, that all is an implementation detail you can ignore. [flow-typed](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/blob/master/README.md) provides a ton of declarations for libraries. Some of these are auto-generated, some of these are put together by humans.

With flow-typed installed, you can grab the library definitions for Jest like so: `flow-typed install jest@22.x.x`. Which should include a `declare function` declaration to make the `test` function a global function that Flow knows about without you having to `require` or `import` the types or functions from anywhere.